# For loop through function

Tags: vb.net, function, for-loop

I tried to draw 64 button(8 rows and 8 columns) to make a game, but for some reason my code does not work. I hope someone can help me with this.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim AMOUNTOF_COLUMNS As Integer = 8
Dim AMOUNTOF_ROWS As Integer = 8
Public Function setNew(row As Integer, column As Integer) As Button

    Dim newButton As New Button()
    newButton.Width = 40
    Me.Controls.Add(newButton)
    newButton.Left = 0
    newButton.Top = 0
    newButton.Height = newButton.Width
    newButton.Text = ""
    newButton.Tag = (column + (row * AMOUNTOF_COLUMNS))
    AddHandler newButton.MouseDown, AddressOf Klik
    Return newButton
End Function

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    For value1 As Integer = 0 To AMOUNTOF_ROWS Step 1
        For value2 As Integer = 0 To AMOUNTOF_COLUMNS Step 1
            Me.setNew(value1, value2)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If I execute this code, it only draws me one button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're drawing 64 buttons but they are all on top of each other. You will need to offset them correctly. Particularly these lines should be modified so that every button gets the correct position.

```
newButton.Left = 0
newButton.Top = 0
```

EDIT:

```
newButton.Tag = "Column x - row y"

Public Sub Klik(sender as Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim b as Button = sender
    Dim value as String = b.Tag
    If value = "Column 1 - row 1" Then
         ' Do action for col 1 row 1
    Else If value = "Column 2 row 1" Then
         ' Do action for col 2 row 1
    Else If ...
    Else If ...
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution did it. Do you know how to add the results of that functions in an array so I can put actions on each button?

Comment: You could add a tag to the button and read from that tag. See the update to my answer

Comment: Can`t figure out how to use the tag. Can you give me some more explanation on how to do this? Am quite new to this and can`t figure it out. Thank you.

Comment: In the tag you can save some arbitrary information (for example a string "column x - row i". Then when the button is clicked you'll get the correct tag with that information so you know which cell was clicked

Comment: And how do I use b.tag to put actions to a button?

Comment: The tag is just a bag which you can put something on. In your handler you should check which button was clicked and then you can do the appropriate action based on the tag. I've updated my answer with an example

Comment: How can I refer to a button made by the setNew function, other than the tagged one?

Comment: In your handler there's no direct way other then to loop over them and find the one with the tag you're looking for.

Comment: And if i put them in an arraylist?
For example I put list.add(newButton) in my setNew function and when I need them I call them by list.Item(index of the button).

Comment: That's also a possibility

Comment: Where do I put the list.add?
Before or after the return newButton? bEcause after the return it throws a nullreferenceexception.

Comment: When you create the button

Comment: Yeah but where in the setNew function do I put the list.add?

Comment: After you've created the button obviously

Comment: Still get an nullreferenceexception.
"Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: Did you create a new list? Please try some things by yourself by debugging the application. SO is not a remote debugging tool.

Comment: Sorry, I will think about it next time.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify you method to draw your buttons next to each other, and set their `Left` and `Top` properties accordingly:

```
Public Function setNew(row As Integer, column As Integer) As Button

    Dim newButton As New Button()
    newButton.Width = 40
    newButton.Height = newButton.Width
    Me.Controls.Add(newButton)
    newButton.Left = column * newButton.Width ' you may need some offset here too
    newButton.Top = row * newButton.Height ' you may need some offset here too
    newButton.Text = ""
    newButton.Tag = (column + (row * AMOUNTOF_COLUMNS))
    AddHandler newButton.MouseDown, AddressOf Klik
    Return newButton
End Function
```

Also, you need to draw one less column and row as you're currently creating 9 rows and columns

```
For value1 As Integer = 0 To AMOUNTOF_ROWS - 1 Step 1
    For value2 As Integer = 0 To AMOUNTOF_COLUMNS -1 Step 1
        Me.setNew(value1, value2)
    Next
Next
```